# Microsoft Azure .NET SDK Sync on Async

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, asynchronous, synchronizationcontext

I am using the Azure Blob Storage SDK `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` for my ASP.NET application. I have seen some synchronous method calling asynchronous method. They use an helper method named `RunWithoutSynchronizationContext` from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util`.

The code is basically doing something like

```
  SynchronizationContext current = SynchronizationContext.Current;
  try
  {
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext((SynchronizationContext) null);
    methodAsync().Wait();
  }
  finally
  {
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(current);
  }
```

I was just wondering if this is a way to avoid deadlock in .NET Framework when blocking on asynchronous code? If not, then what is it the purpose of this method?

Answer (score 0):

One of the common API developer pitfalls in **asynchronous development** with the .Net TPL is **[deadlocks](https://btburnett.com/2016/04/testing-an-sdk-for-asyncawait-synchronizationcontext-deadlocks.html)**. Most commonly, this is caused by SDK consumers **using your asynchronous SDK in a synchronous manner**.

You could use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid deadlocking. Calling this routine before awaiting a task will cause it to ignore the SynchronizationContext.

```
var temp = await methodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, you need to place `ConfigureAwait(false)` calls throughout the SDK, and it is easy to forget.

So the trick is understanding how the `SynchronizationContext` works. Anytime it is used, a call will be made to either it’s Send or Post method. 
So, all we need to do is ensuring that these methods **never get called**:

```
public void Test_SomeActionNoDeadlock()
{
    var context = new Mock<SynchronizationContext>
    {
        CallBase = true
    };
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context.Object);
    try
    {
        context.Verify(m => 
           m.Post(It.IsAny<SendOrPostCallback>(), It.IsAny<object>()), Times.Never);
        context.Verify(m => 
           m.Send(It.IsAny<SendOrPostCallback>(), It.IsAny<object>()), Times.Never);
    }
    finally
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
    }
}
```

Now we have a way to guarantee that ConfigureAwait(false) was used **throughout the SDK method**, so long as we get 100% test coverage through the logical paths in the method.